# How to emulate USB flash drive and read data simultaneous

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have a device that saves screenshots when you put a flash drive with exFAT/FAT32 and a specific directory tree in its USB socket. I want to livestream these screenshots to other devices as fast as possible via ethernet:

device -> flash drive -> ethernet

So I tried an ARM device (Orange Pi Zero) with OTG support and `g_mass_storage` kernel module which emulates an USB flash drive via USB OTG:

> g_mass_storage - To have your Pi Zero appear as a mass storage device
>   (flash drive), first create a mini filesystem in a file on your Pi
>   with `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/piusb.bin bs=512 count=2880` and set it
>   up as a fat32 filesystem with `sudo mkdosfs /piusb.bin`. Then, when
>   enabling it, add `file=/piusb.bin stall=0` onto the end, for example
>   `sudo modprobe g_mass_storage file=/piusb.bin stall=0`.
>
> (from https://gist.github.com/gbaman/50b6cca61dd1c3f88f41)

Next I mounted the emulated flash drive for testing purpose on a Laptop (Linux Mint 18) and the flash drive file via `sudo mount /piusb.bin /mnt/` on the ARM device. But when I add new files/directories in one system it doesn't appear on the other. I have to remount the device/file first to refresh the files.

So is it even possible to read (and stream) the written data at the same time on my ARM device with `g_mass_storage`? Or is there a better way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to remount it.
`sudo umount /mnt/`
`sudo mount /piusb.bin /mnt/`